Modify an Azure logic app workflow from Azure portal
I would like to know, how can an Azure logic app workflow be modified from the Azure portal when:

The source code for the logic app is managed at a remote repository.
Deployment is done via CICD, which reads the source code from the remote repository and do the deployment to Azure cloud.

Note: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE configuration parameter has been set to 1 and changing this to 0 or deleting this followed by a logic app restart will remove the workflows inside the logic app though it allows adding new workflows afterwards. Therefore, this doesn't seem to be a working approach as far as modifying an existing workflow is concerned.
Appreciate inputs on this matter.
Thanks
I tried changing the 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE' configuration parameter value.
I verified my Azure cloud access is sufficient.
